Did XML parsers and schema validators change on XL-Deploy version 22?
I thought that the core of XL Deploy relied on Java-based parsers like JAXB or DOM for XML processing.
I imagined that classes like javax.xml.validation would be embedded in XL-Deploy source code (which unfortunately is proprietary product to which I don't have access)
As of XL Deploy version 22, I don't know if there have been significant changes to XML schema validation compared to previous versions.
But when one of our requesters migrated his XL-Deploy server instance into the XL-Deploy version 22, all the lowercase properties on the synthetic.xml file prevented the deploy. We needed to modify these properties into uppercase so that it would work.

What makes you think this has anything to do with the parsers or schema validators changing? I don't know anything about XL-Deploy, but it seems much more likely to me that the new version has changed the schema or other validation rules.

Hello hello. Thank you for your feedback. Yes, I don't know if this is related to XL-Deploy parsers indeed. But changes in the schema validation were also my guess.
